# Extracting parts of a string

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string, list

I have a string Like `SHD2018101 + SHD2018102 / 26` or it can be `SHD2018101 + SHD2018102 / 26 + SHD2018103`. The string started with **SHD** is  a database table key which is starting with **SHD**. I have to separate the database table key and keep it in a array or in a list to get the value from database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you be more specific about the exact output you want to obtain in both examples?

Comment: Split string using spaces : line.Split(new char[] {' '}).ToArray();

Comment: @jdweng then  how can I remove the operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below should work:

```
string subject = "SHD2018101 + SHD2018102 / 26 + SHD2018103";

StringCollection result = new StringCollection();
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(SHD\d+)");
Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subject);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    result.Add(matchResult.Groups[1].Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```